# RSA-Calculate d without p and q

Tags: rsa

I am given a task to decrypt a message. However, i am only given the value of n and e. So, is it still possible to find the value of d? Is there any shortcut formula that can calculate d without knowing p and q?

Comment: No. That is why RSA is used for real cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

The security of RSA is derived from the difficulty in calculating d from e and n (the public key). It sounds like the task you have been set is essentially to break RSA by factoring n into its prime factors p and q, and then using these to calculate d. Assuming n is not too large, factorization should be relatively easy ([Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) may be able to do it for example).

Comment: but the n value is very huge~

Comment: @JasonKw: "Huge" is not a size, it is an impression. How big, in base 10 digits or bits or hex characters, is n?

Comment: @GregS it is in base 10 digit

Comment: @GregS here's the number
10561558725023445616246137591891481260658760184029982408167649303524274102051504701196516729123506545939738023876846273868174353531186884946817626785858659

Comment: @JasonKw: That is a 512 bit integer

Comment: @JK9 It'll probably take you about a month to factor such a number.